# Datimepicker Not working when displayed on upper side

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I am facing a problem where my bootstrap datetimepicker **cannot work properly** when the datetimepicker  is shown on the **upper side**.

Here is a screenshot:

[image: Show on up]

I **cannot click** anything on the datetimepicker when the datetimepicker shown on the **upper side**

[image: Show on down]

When the datetimepicker is **shown on the lowers side**, I **can click and select** the datetimepicker and it will work properly.

This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
$('#select_year').datepicker({
 format: "yyyy", // Notice the Extra space at the beginning
viewMode: "years", 
minViewMode: "years",
 autoclose: true
});
});
</script>
```

This is how I display the row:

```
        <form action="set_holidays.php" method="post" >
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <label for="field-1"  class="control-label pull-left holiday-vertical"><h4 style='padding-left:10px;'><b>Year</b></h4></label>  
        <div class="col-sm-8"> 
            <div class="input-group date">           
            <input type="text" id="select_year" name="year" class="form-control years" value="$this->year">
              <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Go</button>
                        <input type='hidden' value='refresh' name='action'>
                    </span>
            </div>
        </div>                        
             </div>                                    
    </form>
```

This is how i **included js and css**

```
<link type="text/css" href="mypath/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link type="text/css" href="mypath/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link type="text/css" href="mypath/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="mypath/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="mypath/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="mypath/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
```

Comment: There is more than one datepicker for jQuery/Twitter-bootstrap you may want to reference which you are using so others can better evaluate your issue.

Comment: Try to set the 'z-index' style for your datepicker's container to '16777271' and see if it works for you.

Comment: @choz just curious, how come you know there is another object with z-index-16777270  ?

Comment: @CrandellWS Hi, i have upated my question

Comment: Thanks, but I still do not know where was the `bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css` `datepicker.css` and `bootstrap-datepicker.js` files where obtained from there for, it is unclear what is in them.

Comment: @CrandellWS what is the way to provide you?

Comment: a link to where you obtained the datepicker from is fine for me

Comment: @Ryan I am just saying to set it to the most top index, that value is the max index for opera..

Comment: @choz i see. thanks for the sharing. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an assumption that you are using the datepicker from http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker which has an option for orientation that could be set as `orientation: "top auto"` which would keep the calendar's top against the input box.

See the sinppet

```js
$(function() {
  $('#select_year').datepicker({
    format: "yyyy", // Notice the Extra space at the beginning
    viewMode: "years",
    minViewMode: "years",
    autoclose: true,
    orientation: "top auto"
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker/css/datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<form action="set_holidays.php" method="post">
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <label for="field-1" class="control-label pull-left holiday-vertical">
      <h4 style='padding-left:10px;'><b>Year</b></h4>
    </label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <div class="input-group date">
        <input type="text" id="select_year" name="year" class="form-control years" value="$this->year">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Go</button>
          <input type='hidden' value='refresh' name='action'>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```